# what is $T^{1/2}$ consistent?

Tags: regression, self-study, least-squares, consistency

the OLS estimators of the short-run parameters are $T^{1/2}$ consistent. What is the$T^{1/2}$ consistent ?

Comment: A closely related question was asked here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207264/root-n-consistent-estimator-but-root-n-doesnt-converge/207281#207281

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the model be, $y=X\beta+e$ where $e_i\sim i.i.d N(0,\sigma^2<\infty)$ and $i=1,2,\ldots,T$. Then square root consistency means,

$$
\sqrt T (\beta-\hat\beta)\overset{d}{\rightarrow} N(0,(X'X)^{-1} \sigma^2)
$$

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. I have two more questions. First one is that what is asymptotically singular ? and second one what is asymptotically perfectly collinear? Please give an explanation thank you again :)

Comment: You should really ask this as new questions! Comments is not the place for new questions. And, please include some more context than in this question.

Comment: As @kjetilbhalvorsen suggests, you should go for a new question with more details.

Comment: Actually, the answer is not correct. First the asymptotic variance has too many X and second lim is imprecise in terms of the convergence mode.

Comment: @ChristophHanck Thanks, I fixed that. What do you mean by the second lim?

Comment: The situation that you are describing is convergence in distribution, for which we commonly use notation like $\to_d$, and not $\lim$, which concerns deterministic sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Let the model be, $y=X\beta+e$ where $e_i\sim i.i.d N(0,\sigma^2<\infty)$ and $i=1,2,\ldots,T$. Then by central limit theorem:

$$
\sqrt T (\beta-\hat\beta)\overset{d}{\rightarrow} N(0,(X'X)^{-1} \sigma^2)
$$

This in turn implies that $$\sqrt T (\beta-\hat\beta) = O_P(1)$$
The above equation defines "$\hat{\beta}$ is $\sqrt{n}$-consistent".

What does that definition mean? For some statistic $Z_n$, $Z_n = O_P(1)$ i.e. $Z_n$ is "bounded in probability" means the following:
for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a constant $C_{\varepsilon}$ such that:
$$
\mathbb{P}(|Z_n| > C_{\varepsilon}) \leq \varepsilon
$$

For more details also see: [root-n consistent estimator, but root-n doesn't converge?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207264/root-n-consistent-estimator-but-root-n-doesnt-converge/207281#207281)