# $\sqrt{n}$-consistent and strongly consistent

Tags: mean, consistency

Can you show that $\bar{X}$ is a $\sqrt{n}$-consistent and strongly consistent for $\mu$?  Where $X_1, X_2,..., X_n$ be iid from $P\in{\wp}$ and $\mu$, mean of $P$ is assumed to be finite.

Comment: What is the mean of $\mathbf{P}$? May be you wanted to say the mean of $X_{i}$?

Comment: related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207264/root-n-consistent-estimator-but-root-n-doesnt-converge/207281#207281

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statements are the weak and strong laws of large numbers, respectively.

The proofs can be found, for example, in

[https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~tracy/courses/math135A/UsefullCourseMaterial/lawLargeNo.pdf](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Etracy/courses/math135A/UsefullCourseMaterial/lawLargeNo.pdf)