# What is the meaning of squared root n when we talk about asymptotic properties?

Tags: asymptotics

I just wonder what is the meaning or intuition behind $\sqrt{n}$ before $(\hat\beta-\beta)$ when we talk about asymptotic normality. Where does $\sqrt{n}$ come from?

$\sqrt{n}(\hat\beta-\beta)\xrightarrow{ d }N(0,\sigma^2)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It "comes from" the central limit theorem, see [What intuitive explanation is there for the central limit theorem?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3734/what-intuitive-explanation-is-there-for-the-central-limit-theorem). It turns out that for many, although clearly not all estimators, scaling the estimation error $\hat\beta-\beta$ by $\sqrt{n}$ yields a nondegenerate asymptotic normal distribution.

See [root-n consistent estimator, but root-n doesn't converge?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207264/root-n-consistent-estimator-but-root-n-doesnt-converge) for further discussion.

See [Estimation of unit-root AR(1) model with OLS](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145864/estimation-of-unit-root-ar1-model-with-ols/145877#145877) for an example of an estimator that does not converge at the $\sqrt{n}$ rate.